# C language AST using GADTs and constructor subsets

Tags: haskell

I would like to define type level safe C language AST. So far, I come up with with something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Defn
  = Func String [Block]

type Block = forall a. BlockItem a
type Stmt = BlockItem StmtType

data BlockItemKind = StmtType

data BlockItem :: BlockItemKind -> * where
  Var :: String -> Expr -> BlockItem a
  SideEff :: Expr -> BlockItem StmtType
  Return :: Expr -> BlockItem StmtType

data Expr
  = Lit Int
```

The key point is the `BlockItem` data type. In C standard, there are two very similar structures – block and statements. Block is basically just list of statements that can also contain variable declaration. In this code, I'm trying to declare statement as subset of block items constructors (as `SideEff` and `Return`).

However, this code does not work as expected. Consider following code which is printing this AST:

```
showDefn :: Defn -> String
showDefn (Func name block) = "func " ++ name ++ " . " ++ show (showBlock <$> block)

showBlock :: Block -> String
showBlock (Var name e) = name ++ " = " ++ showExpr e ++ ";"
showBlock e = showStmt e

showStmt :: Stmt -> String
showStmt (SideEff e) = showExpr e ++ ";"
showStmt (Return e) = "return " ++ showExpr e ++ ";"

showExpr :: Expr -> String
showExpr (Lit x) = show x
```

When I'm evaluating `showDefn` with `[Block]`, everything works well. This code however not work when I'm using `Stmt` type:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- FOLLOWING WORK
  print $ showDefn (Func "foo" [Var "a" (Lit 2), Var "b" (Lit 3)])

  -- FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
  print $ showDefn (Func "foo" [Return (Lit 0)])
  print $ showDefn (Func "foo" [Var "a" (Lit 1), SideEff (Lit 2)])
```

You can run the code [here](https://repl.it/@Nutelac/CheapOliveSearchservice).

Where is the problem? I'm not even sure, if this is the right design.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. In C a block is just a type of statement ("compound statement").

Comment: `forall a. BlockItem a` is something that can be tagged with *every* statement type simultaneously (only `Var` has this property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Haskell pro-tip:  If you ever find yourself having to use the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension, take your hands off the keyboard and back away from the computer.)

Anyway, to elaborate on @luqui's comment, the type `Defn` is equivalent to:

```
data Defn = Func String [forall a. BlockItem a]
```

This is a product type of a `String` and a list.  The elements of the list have type `forall a. BlockItem a`, which is the type of things that can be `BlockItem a` for any `a` (as chosen by the caller/user of the value).  As @luqui points out, `Var "a" (Lit 2)` has this type -- it can be a `BlockItem a` for any possible `a`, but your other block items can't.  For example, `Return (Lit 0)` can only be `BlockItem a` when `a` is a `StmtType`, so it can't be put in a `[forall a. BlockItem a]` list -- the type is too general for it.

It's analogous to the following type, which allows storage of things that can be any kind of `Num`:

```
data NumList = NL [forall a. Num a => a]
```

Because `3` and `18 - 1` can be any kind of `Num`, we can put them in the list:

```
mylist = NL [3, 18-1]
```

Later, we can extract one of the element of this list:

```
NL [_,x] = mylist
```

and treat it as any kind of `Num` we want:

```
> x :: Integer
17
> x :: Double
17.0
```

But we can't put a specific `Num` type (e.g., an `Int`) into the list:

```
badlist = NL [length "hello"]  -- type error
```

If we could, then we could write:

```
> let NL [x] = badlist in sqrt x
```

to take the `sqrt` of an `Int`, and all "type hell" would break loose.

So, that's what you're doing *wrong*.  It's hard to tell how you should do it *right*.  Why doesn't the following work for you, without GADTs and DataKinds?

```
data Defn = Func String [BlockItem]

data BlockItem
  = Var String Expr
  | Stmt Statement

data Statement
  = SideEff Expr
  | Return Expr

data Expr
  = Lit Int
```